Nodemailer is not sending emails
I've setted up transformer as
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "Gmail",
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.GMAIL,
    pass: process.env.GPASSWORD,
  },
});

and here is my route which is used for sending mails
router.post("/forgetpassword", async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({ username: username });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
  }

  const userID = shortId.generate();
  const entry = await Password.create({
    username: username,
    userID: userID,
  });
  if (entry) {
    try {
      const resetPasswordLink = Frontend_URL + "/reset/" + userID;

      var mailOptions = {
        from: `"CampusLink" <${process.env.GMAIL}>`,
        to: username,
        subject: "Reset Your Password",
        html: `
        <p>Hello,</p>
        <p>We received a request to reset your password. Click the link below to reset your password:</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" href="${resetPasswordLink}">Reset Password</a></p>
        <p><strong>Please note that this link is valid for only 5 minutes.</strong></p>
        <p>If you didn't request this, you can safely ignore this email.</p>
        <p>Best regards,<br/>CampusLink Team</p>
      `,
      };

      const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

      res.status(200).json({message: "Success"});
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({message: "Failed to send mail"});
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error!" });
  }
});

But it is not working as expected, the password reset mails are not receiving. Earlier without using async await I used promises and on that I receive mails 5-6 minutes later, and now I changed to async/await but I am not receiving any mails.

It's pretty difficult to help you without a minimal working example, but based purely on reading the code I suspect its probably one of the following things:

shortId.generate() seems like something that returns a promise and needs an await? Though that should not actually stop the email from sending and only make the reset link something like /reset/<object object>...
to: username seems like it might be incorrect, perhaps you meant to use something like user.email? Unless username is actually a valid email address of course.

Also note that sendMail returns a SentMessageInfo object, which contains more specific information on the state of the different recipients:
interface SentMessageInfo {
    /** includes the envelope object for the message */
    envelope: MimeNode.Envelope;
    /** most transports should return the final Message-Id value used with this property */
    messageId: string;
    accepted: Array<string | Mail.Address>;
    rejected: Array<string | Mail.Address>;
    pending: Array<string | Mail.Address>;
    response: string;
}

I believe it's possible the username is still in the pending array and the sendMail call executes without throwing an error because of it.
I'v never used nodemailer with Gmail though so that's just speculation

Okay thanks for your concern, but I understood the problem, When I am sending links through nodemailer, nodemailer successfully sends the email but somehow google blocks the email and send back it after 5 minutes maybe they check the links?, and if I send the mail without any links the mail gets received within seconds. Do you know any better ways to send links so that they can't be blocked by google?, till then I have to rely on OTP's instead

Hmm, I've never used Gmail for a system like this so I really don't know how or indeed if this can be solved at all. Unless you want to tell your users to 5 minutes of course..
